# Rootless Podman Containers: and setting secure permissions/SELinux on attached storage

Tags: linux, containers, storage, selinux, podman

I am reading conflicting info about this and would like some clarification.

**Issue/Question**
What are the secure permissions settings for attached directories as storage on containers

I would think that the following is the most secure. No/

```html
#While as user_1 for example
sudo mkdir /containers/web_server1;
sudo chown user_1:user_1 /containers/web_server1;
sudo chmod 750 /containers/web_server1;

Then set semanage fcontext to container_file_t  for /containers/web_server1
```

Why am I seeing in books and online tutorials to set permissions to 777 or 757.  What am I missunderstanding here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can now try  [podman 4.0.0](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/tag/v4.0.0) (and [latest releases](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/) like 4.0.2) from Feb. 2022.

The issue [12173 "podman pod create needs to support `--security-opt`"](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12173) has been resolved with [PR 12208](https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/12208)

> ### Pod Security Option support and Infra Inheritance changes
>
> Added support for pod security options.
>
> These are applied to infra and passed down to the containers as added (unless overridden).

The [security options](https://github.com/cdoern/podman/blob/289270375a54c26b86f9e2d99aab18b427e56b88/docs/source/markdown/podman-pod-create.1.md#--security-optoption) include:

> - `apparmor=unconfined` : Turn off apparmor confinement for the pod
> - `apparmor=your-profile` : Set the apparmor confinement profile for the pod
> - `seccomp=unconfined` : Turn off seccomp confinement for the pod
> - `seccomp=profile.json` : Whitelisted syscalls seccomp Json file to be used as a seccomp filter